# BaseUrl is not working in universal-cli but it works in the angular-cli

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, tsconfig, universal-cli

So I've got a problem which I don't know how to fix..

Basically I'm using `"baseUrl": "."` in my `tsconfig.json` file which allow me to do `imports` starting from the root folder. But when I'm using the `universal-cli` which supports universal, and then run `ung serve` (`ng serve`) it runs it from the `dist` folder. But I get an error saying `Cannot find module app/shared`.

Why can it no longer find the shared folder? Doesn't make sense that it would work in the normal `angular-cli` when it doesn't serve via the `dist` folder. Or does it make sense? Any pointers here would be great because I don't know how to proceed. I've tried setting different `baseUrl`s but I get the same result no matter what.